# Create a column with the aggregated values of another column in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, aggregate-functions, lag

I have a column of values and want to create another column with the aggregated values of the first column.

```
df <- c(x = 0, y = 0)
df$x <- c(1:5)
df$y <- df$x + lag(df$y, default = 0)
> df
$x
[1] 1 2 3 4 5

$y
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

My expectation is that the value of y equals: 1 3 6 10 15.
What do I do wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

We may need `cumsum`

```
df$y <- cumsum(df$x)
```

---

Or `accumulate`

```
library(purrr)
accumulate(df$x, `+`)
[1]  1  3  6 10 15
```